# MongoDB Aggregate - How to get array of fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am using MongoDB aggregation framework, suppose I am having collection structure like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(123)
    name: john,
    sessionDuration: 29
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(456)
    name: moore,
    sessionDuration: 45
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(789)
    name: cary,
    sessionDuration: 25
  },
]
```

I want to query and create a pipeline such that it returns something like this:

```
{
  durationsArr: [29, 49, 25, '$sessionDuration_Field_From_Document' ];
}
```

I am doing this because I want to get the average of durations from all the documents, so first add all of it into an array, then I will add the last stage where I do the `$avg` operation.

Any idea of how can I get the array of `sessionDurationField`? Or do you have any other best approach to calculate the `sessionDuration` average from the collection? Please thoroughly explain am new to MongoDB aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group all documents.

   1.1. `$avg` - Calculate the average of `sessionDuration` for all documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      avgSessionDuration: {
        $avg: "$sessionDuration"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XJtTzrQXdP9)